# Can niece not connect to my paternal line but her daughter connects to my maternal and paternal side?

Tags: united-states, dna, autosomal-dna, relationship-analysis, family-tree

My niece is a dna match 2112 cM over 80 segments. She only matches on my maternal side of the family.
Her daughter is a dna match of 1118 cM over 46 segments. She matches both my maternal and paternal side extensively. Her father has no matches to my side of the family at all. The ancestry is saying my brother is a half brother. Is it even possible for my grand niece to have dna that her mother doesn't have??

Comment: Hi, welcome to G&FH.SE! Could you clarify a couple of things?  1) Is your niece your brother's child? 2) You say "The Ancestry is saying my brother is a half brother" -- do you mean AncestryDNA, and has he tested? 3) Your question could be improved by assigning initials to the people involved (for privacy, make them different than the actual initials of your relatives) so we can tell who you mean when you say "she".

Comment: https://dnapainter.com/tools/sharedcmv4/2112 https://dnapainter.com/tools/sharedcmv4/1118

Comment: Yes my niece is my brother's child.s I am DJ my niece is NJ with 2112 cM over 80 segments. Her daughter(my grand niece) is OS with 1118 cM over 46 segments. OS father has no matches in my tree.

Comment: Yes my niece is my brother's child he is not tested. Ancestry DNA is saying he is a half brother. I am DJ my niece is NJ with 2112 cM over 80 segments. Her daughter(my grand niece) is OS with 1118 cM over 46 segments. OS's father has no matches in my tree .NJ (my niece) does not have any matches with my paternal line, All NJ's matches are on my mother's side.  OS (my grand niece has many matches on both my maternal and paternal side.